# Console script. Child processes become zombies when cUrl is used

Tags: php, unix, curl, multiprocessing

Console script perform data import from external API. For boosting import loading performed in concurrent processes that is created by  `pcntl_fork` command.
For communication with API cUrl is used. Communication performed by https protocol.

By some undefined reason periodically some children becomes zombie. There is no errors/warnings/notices in console and also there is not logs is written. Errors level is configured appropriately.

After investigation I suppose that there problem in curl extension since without it, with fake connection, there is no problems.
Also if run import in single process mode - there is no problems at all.

PHP: 7.2.4,
OS: Debian 9,
Curl: 7.59.0 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.47.0 OpenSSL/1.0.2g zlib/1.2.8 libidn/1.32 librtmp/2.3

Maybe someone encountered similar problem or know possible reasons of this strange behavior?

Pseudo code sample of child logic (main part of child showed):

```
while (true) {
        $socket->writeRawString(Signal::MESSAGE_REQUEST_DATA);
        $response = $socket->readRawString();
        if (Signal::MESSAGE_TERMINATE_PROCESS === $response) {
            break;
        }
        $response = json_decode($response, true);
        if (empty($response) || empty($response['deltaId'])) {
            continue;
        }
        $delta = $this->providerConnection->getChanges($response['deltaId']);
        if(empty($delta)) {
            continue;
        }
        $xmlReader = new \XMLReader();
        $xmlReader->XML($delta);
        $xmlReader->read();
        $xmlReader->read();
        $hasNext = true;
        while ($hasNext && 'updated' !== $xmlReader->name) {
            $hasNext = $xmlReader->next();
        }
        if ('updated' !== $xmlReader->name) {
            throw new \RuntimeException('Deltas file do not contain updated date.');
        }
        if (strtotime($xmlReader->readString()) < $endDateTimestamp) {
            $socket->writeRawString(self::SIGNAL_END_DATE_REACHED);
            continue;
        }
    }
    posix_kill(\posix_getpid(), SIGTERM);
```

In `providerConnection->getChanges($response['deltaId']);` request performed via cUrl. For work with cUrl used [Php cUrl class](https://github.com/php-curl-class/php-curl-class) extension

Comment: That's a rather broad question with no code at all so the best anyone might be able to do is guess.

Comment: You have to make sure that you collect all child-processes after they are finished (`pcntl_waitpid` or `pcntl_wait`)

Comment: @Dave, I think code do not bring any clearance to this problem. Main point here that by some reason child that is execute request via cUrl using https connection is got zombie state while parent is continue to run. I know that my question is to broad but this is all that I know about problem.

Comment: @TomRegner, Question is about possible explanations of strange child process interruption. They become zombies while parent is still running.

Comment: Do you have a signal-trap for SIGCHLD and it doesn't trigger? A minimal code example showing the behaviour would help.

Comment: @TomRegner, I added code sample of child logic. This is extraction of code from different abstract layers. I dont have any custom signal handlers. Communication between parent and children performed by Unix stream sockets. If child receive message about termination from parent, it brake infinite loop and finish itself by ` posix_kill(\posix_getpid(), SIGTERM)` command.
Or maybe you mean other code?

Comment: The parent has to collect it's child-processes; after the process is killed, the system will emit a SIGCHLD signal, you will have to install a signal handler and handle these signals.

Comment: @TomRegner, at the current moment I don't see relation between missing signal handlers and possible unexpected behavior of cUrl in parallel processes. Could you, please, be more descriptive.

Comment: I'll write more tomorrow, for now I only can reiterate: If the parent does not collect a dead child with wait/waitpid, the child will be a zombie -- when the parent dies, init will take over and collect the children; but the parent process is responsible for it's children as long as it lives itself -- double fork the children to forego this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I give up using cUrl for my task. Today I switched to Guzzle with StreamHandler instead of cUrl and it solved all my problems.

I suppose, that due to some internal errors in cUrl, system was killing my child processes.

This is not answer to my question. It just workaround of my problem for those who may also encounter similar problem.

Topic is still open for possible suggestions/explanations.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in my comments, your problem probably is, that childprocesses that died/finished need to be collected by the parent process, or they remain as zombies.

First solution:

Install a signal handler in the parent. Something like this:

```
pcntl_signal(SIGCHLD, [$this, 'handleSignals']);
```

With a signal handler that could look like this:

```
/**
 * @param integer $signal
 */
public function handleSignals($signal) {
    switch($signal) {
        case SIGCHLD:
                do { 
                    $pid = pcntl_wait($status, WNOHANG);
                } while($pid > 0);
            break;
        default:
            //Nothing to do
    }
}
```

I normally store the pids of forked children and check them all individually with `pcntl_waitpid`, but this could get you going.

Second Solution:

Use a double-fork to spawn the child-processes, if the parent does not need to wait for all sub-tasks to finish.  A double fork looks like this:

```
$pid = pcntl_fork();
if ($pid == -1) handleError();
elseif ($pid ==  0) { // child
    $pid = pcntl_fork(); 
    if ($pid == -1) handleChildError();
    elseif($pid == 0) { // second level child
        exit(startWork()); // init will take over this process
    }  
    // exit first level child
    exit(0);
} else {
    // parent, wait for first level child
    pcntl_wait($pid, $status); // forked child returns almost immediatly, so blocking wait is in order
}
```

Comment: As I written yesterday, problem was caused by cUrl. Zombies was a result of strange cUrl behavior in children (10-30 children simultaneously used it). Main goal of my topic was to collect suggestions about possible solutions(explanations) of problem with cUrl.
But thanks for your answer.

Comment: It is only a curl problem if curl is forking, if your code forks the childprocesses, it is your problem. Even if the behavior is only exhibited by childprocesses doing the real thing, doesn't mean the real thing is your problem -- after all, a zombie process is a dead/finished process not collected by its parent...; is the work done, and the child terminated by the posix_kill, or does it error out inmidst of its workload with a curl error? then its a curl problem -- but not the problem you enquire about here. Maybe I'm wrong, but than you are asking the wrong question. Bye for now

Comment: From the beginning my topic was about problems with cUrl. Maybe only title was not clear enough. In comments I emphasized that it about cUrl. But you stuck on processes and start to explain obvious things that in any way will not help to solve problem. That's all.

Comment: English is not my first language -- you were asking specificly about zombie processes and had no curl related code in the question; probably my bad